# Passing data from one TableView to another TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, pass-data

I have setup a prepare for segue method and I believe I have successfully sent my data to the second ViewController but I'm unsure how to use the passed data.

**For Example:**

[image: Picture]

When the user taps Protein I want to send to the second tableViewController protein was selected and then populate it with an array of protein.

Below is my first tableview code:

**First TableView:**

```
class OrdersTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        var titleList = ["Protein","Protein Flavor", "Base", "Base Flavor", "Side", "Additional"]

        // MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return titleList.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! OrdersTableViewCell

            cell.cellTitle.text = titleList[indexPath.row]

            // Configure the cell...

            return cell
        }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if (segue.identifier == "showDetailView") {
                let DVC = segue.destination as! OrderDetailTableViewController

                if let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let proteins = titleList[indexpath.row] as String
                    DVC.sentData1 = proteins

                    print (proteins)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently if I print the value that's being sent it seems to be working. In this case it prints "Protein". But ideally this is what I want, but I'm unsure how to do it.

```
class OrderDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var sentData1:String!
    var proteinList = ["Salmon", "Meatballs", "Chicken", "Cod","Sausage", "Frittata"]
    var baseList = ["White Rice", "Brown Rice"]

    //take what is selected from sentData1 and populate second tableview

    if sentData1 == "Protein" {
        //populate tableview with proteinList
    }

    if sentData1 == "Base" {
        //populate tableview with baseList
    }
```

All the posts I've found deal with a TableView sending data to a normal viewController which I haven't found useful when trying to implement it. I'm brand new to Swift so any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest setting up a data structure to represent your information rather than multiple string arrays.  Here's a simple example:

```
class Nutrient {
    var kind: String
    var examples: [String]

    init(_ kind: String, examples: [String] = []) {
        self.kind = kind
        self.examples = examples
    }
}

let dataModel = [Nutrient("Protein", examples:["Salmon", "Meatballs", "Chicken", "Cod","Sausage", "Frittata"]),
                 Nutrient("Base", examples:["White Rice", "Brown Rice"])]
```

With that, you would use the nutrient `kind` field to populate your first table and pass the nutrient `examples` array to your second table.  The second table wouldn't need to know about anything except what it's given to display.

Comment: I agree, having an actual data structure would make your code base much better!

Comment: where would I implement this to make it work? I like this idea

Comment: It depends on how complex the real data is.  If it's only static information, you can do it where you currently create `titleList`.  For a data model where the user could add/delete/modify items, you would probably want a "manager" class to handle access through a shared instance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a triggering your segue from a on tap in your storyboard, you could remove that trigger and simply have that segue point from one viewController to your second VC.  Then add a `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //save the selectedIndex in a class variable
    selectedIndex = indexPath
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailView", nil)
}
```

Then in your prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showDetailView") {
            let DVC = segue.destination as! OrderDetailTableViewController
            DVC.sentData1 = titleList[selectedIndex.row]
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
class OrderDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var sentData1:String!
    var secondTableViewDataSource : [String] = []
    var proteinList = ["Salmon", "Meatballs", "Chicken", "Cod","Sausage", "Frittata"]
    var baseList = ["White Rice", "Brown Rice"]

//take what is selected from sentData1 and populate second tableview
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    switch sentData1 {
    case "Protein":
        secondTableViewDataSource = proteinList
        //you may need to call tableView.reloadData() here too
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

*I wanted to add since I seen that your are using a `UITableViewController` while there is nothing wrong with that...using a `UIViewController` and subscribing to the UITableViewDataSource/Delegate protocols would allow much more flexibility.  I hardly ever use actual `UITableViewController`s